# Finding the number of real solutions of $2 \cos((x^2+x)/6) = 2^x + 2^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> The number of real roots of the equation
>   $$
>  2\cos\left(\frac{x^2+x}{6}\right) = 2^x + 2^{-x}
> $$
>   is
>
> 1. $0$,
> 2. $1$,
> 3. $2$,
> 4. infinitely many.

I can see that $x=0$ satisfies the equation. But I do not know how to solve the equation explicitly.
Thanks

Comment: Not cropping an image, again; and retyping this bit of text would not take you all that long. This being your 127th question, you should know MathJax by now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

we have $$2\cos\left(\frac{x^2+x}{6}\right)=2^x+2^{-x}\geq 2\sqrt{2^x\cdot 2^{-x}}=2$$ by AM-GM thus we have $$2\cos\left(\frac{x^2+x}{6}\right)\geq 2$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: Means $cos() \geq 1$. But cos term is not greater than 1. So we consider case where it is equal to 1 which occurs at x=0. Is that right?

Comment: yes that is right!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $\cos$ function gives value 1 at $2\pi,4\pi\cdots$ also. Why don't we consider those values?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The minimum of $y + \frac 1 y$ over $y > 0$ is exactly $2$, attained when $y = 1$.

Comment: So what should be done next

Comment: @TaylorTed Well, did you think about the hint at all? Do you see how this might be relevant to your equation?

Comment: So x=0 is only solutions

Answer (score 0):

$$2\cos((x^2+x)/6)≥2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \cos((x^2+x)/6)≥1$$
Now as $\cos 0=1,$ then

$$(x^2+x)/6=0$$

then $x(x+1)=0$

and then $x=0, x=-1$ are the solutions.
So ans is $(3),$ i.e. there are two solutions.

Comment: $x=-1$ doesn't minimize the RHS.